# Initialize Wygwam within Custom Fieldtype

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, add-on-development, fieldtype

I'm developing a fieldtype add-on and within the fieldtype, I would like to include the option to let users choose Wygwam as the text element, if they have it installed.

Is there some sort of a "build" method in Wygwam I can use within my fieldtype? Similar to the way the native RTE has the following, which you can use to initialize and assign it to text areas:

```
ee()->rte_lib->build_js(0, '.textarea_class', NULL, TRUE);
```

Anyone know if Wygwam has something similar, or anyone have experience in using Wygwam within their own fieldtype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it before. Take a look at the `display_field` method of ft.wygwam.php. You'll see that it's fairly simple to instantiate a WYGWAM field. A few calls to the Wygwam_Helper class to load the JS/CSS. There are also some helpers for properly formatting the data. You'll need a textarea with an id, and also the ID number of a WYGWAM config. I don't want to replicate their code here, since it's proprietary, but this should send you in the right direction.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I was able to get this to work using the following lines: `require_once(PATH_THIRD . 'wygwam/ft.wygwam.php');
$wyg = new Wygwam_ft();
$wyg->_init(array('field_name' => 'field_id_85', 'settings' => array('config' => 1, 'defer' => 'y')));
$wyg->display_field($text);`